# Duplicate Targets Can't Find Class Referenced in Storyboard - Original Target Can.

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

This one is driving me nuts.

I have a workspace with two projects. Each project represents a different app (let's call them "Banana" and "Orange"). Some source files are shared, some are app specific. The same applies to the storyboards.

So far, so good.

I had to duplicate the app target for Orange because I needed two special configurations for testing, so I created the targets "Orange_A" and "Orange_B".

When I build the targets Orange_A or Orange_B, and run them, the app crashes because there is one view controller that fails to be loaded from the storyboard:

> Unknown class XXXXXX in Interface Builder file.

The source file for the class **is** present in the "Compile Resources" phase of **all three targets**.

When I inspect the view controller in Interface builder, the class is set and the arrow button correctly jumps to the source file.

The "module" field for that view controller an another one displays "Orange"; all the others Display "Current - Banana" in gray.

However, when opening the storyboard as Source File, the "custom module" attribute is just "Banana" in all other view controllers, and "Orange" in the two.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if target have access to file in Target Membership section both targets needs to be selected this is probably the problem

[image: Target membership]

Comment: The target membership (as well as presence in "Compile Sources") is OK. I fixed it by moving the offending view controller to its dedicated storyboard. Then, something similar started to happen with other classes. They all had a specific value in the "module" field of the inspector; I cleared the value so that "Current - Whatever" is displayed in grey instead, and now it works...